# what's the advantage of message queue over shared data in thread communication?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, message-queue

I read a article about multithread program design http://drdobbs.com/architecture-and-design/215900465, it says it's a best practice that "replacing shared data with asynchronous messages. As much as possible, prefer to keep each thread’s data isolated (unshared), and let threads instead communicate via asynchronous messages that pass copies of data".

What confuse me is that I don't see the difference between using shared data and message queues. I am now working on a non-gui project on windows, so let's use windows's message queues. and take a tradition producer-consumer problem as a example.

Using shared data, there would be a shared container and a lock guarding the container between the producer thread and the consumer thread. when producer output product, it first wait for the lock and then write something to the container then release the lock.

Using message queue, the producer could simply PostThreadMessage without block. and this is the async message's advantage. but I think there must exist some lock guarding the message queue between the two threads, otherwise the data will definitely corrupt. the PostThreadMessage call just hide the details. I don't know whether my guess is right but if it's true, the advantage seems no longer exist,since both two method do the same thing and the only difference is that the system hide the details when using message queues.

ps. maybe the message queue use a non-blocking containner, but I could use a concurrent container in the former way too. I want to know how the message queue is implemented and is there any performance difference bwtween the two ways?

updated:
I still don't get the concept of async message if the message queue operations are still blocked somewhere else. Correct me if my guess was wrong: when we use shared containers and locks we will block in our own thread. but when using message queues, myself's thread returned immediately, and left the blocking work to some system thread.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

***Message passing*** is useful for exchanging smaller amounts of data, because no conflicts need be avoided. It's much easier to implement than is shared memory for intercomputer communication. Also, as you've already noticed, message passing has the advantage that application developers don't need to worry about the details of protections like shared memory.

***Shared memory*** allows maximum speed and convenience of communication, as it can be done at memory speeds when within a computer. Shared memory is usually faster than message passing, as *message-passing are typically implemented using system calls and thus require the more time-consuming tasks of kernel intervention*. In contrast, in shared-memory systems, system calls are required only to establish shared-memory regions. Once established, all access are treated as normal memory accesses w/o extra assistance from the kernel.

**Edit**: One case that you might want implement your own queue is that there are lots of messages to be produced and consumed, e.g., a logging system. With the implemenetation of PostThreadMessage, its queue capacity is fixed. Messages will most liky get lost if that capacity is exceeded.

Comment: So the only difference is that the message passing hides the details? if I myself use a mutex and a queue, it should be at least as much as efficient as message queue?

Comment: That depends. The system provided message-queue is well designed to handle synchronization effectively. Why do you need reinvent the wheels?

Comment: I still don't get the concept of async message if the message queue operations are still blocked somewhere else. Correct me if my guess was wrong: when we use shared containers and locks we will block in our own thread. but when using message queues, myself's thread returned immediately, and left the blocking work to some system thread.

Comment: Good catch. Yes, with shared memory, all the other threads trying to access the CS will be blocked until the current one exists. As to async message passing, the sending thread won't be blocked as long as the queue buffer is not full. Whether there is some kernel thread that gets blocked, this is the thing I'm not sure. If basic operations(add/remove) on queue are implemented as a primitive, it is trivial then.

Answer (score 8):

Imagine you have 1 thread producing data,and 4 threads processing that data (presumably to make use of a multi core machine). If you have a big global pool of data you are likely to have to lock it when *any* of the threads needs access, potentially blocking 3 other threads. As you add more processing threads you increase the chance of a lock having to wait *and* increase how many things might have to wait. Eventually adding more threads achieves nothing because all you do is spend more time blocking.

If instead you have one thread sending messages into message queues, one for each consumer thread then they can't block each other. You stil have to lock the queue between the producer and consumer threads but as you have a separate queue for each thread you have a separate lock and each thread can't block all the others waiting for data.

If you suddenly get a 32 core machine you can add 20 more processing threads (and queues) and expect that performance will scale fairly linearly unlike the first case where the new threads will just run into each other all the time.

Comment: I don't know why nobody voted up - you made an excellent point about shared memory blocking! Thank you, good head on your shoulders buddy. Honestly, something about the way you put it - this should be the answer to the question :)

Answer (score 2):

Of course there is "shared data" when you pass messages. After all, the message itself is some sort of data. However, the important distinction is when you pass a message, the consumer will receive a **copy**.

> the PostThreadMessage call just hide the details

Yes, it does, but being a WINAPI call, you can be reasonably sure that it does it right.

> I still don't get the concept of async message if the message queue operations are still blocked somewhere else.

The **advantage** is more safety. You have a locking mechanism that is systematically enforced when you are passing a message. You don't even need to think about it, you can't forget to lock. Given that multi-thread bugs are some of the nastiest ones (think of race conditions), this is very important. Message passing is a higher level of abstraction built on locks.

The **disadvantage** is that passing large amounts of data would be probably slow. In that case, you need to use need shared memory.

For passing state (i.e. worker thread reporting progress to the GUI) the messages are the way to go.

Comment: Copy?  When I pass messages, I try very hard to avoid copying anything except object pointers.  Why would I want to copy bulk data?  Copying is expensive and often requires a lock around the copy.

Comment: @MartinJames If you are passing the pointers in the messages, then you are back to square one (i.e. you are essentially sharing data) and have to do some form of lock management to prevent simultaneous reading-writing and writing-writing from different threads.

Comment: Not really. The object pointers I pass always point to different objects, so no locking needed during procesing.

Comment: No, you are sharing the ownership of the object, because there will be one owner in the originating thread and another in the receiving one.

Comment: No.  Different object = no contention.  The producer relinquishes ownership when it pushes the message and immediately allocates, or depools, another object pointer.

Answer (score 2):

I have used a shared memory model where the pointers to the shared memory are managed in a message queue with careful locking. In a sense, this is a hybrid between a message queue and shared memory. This is very when large quantities of data must be passed between threads while retaining the safety of the message queue.

The entire queue can be packaged in a single C++ class with appropriate locking and the like. The key is that the queue owns the shared storage and takes care of the locking. Producers acquire a lock for input to the queue and receive a pointer to the next available storage chunk (usually an object of some sort), populates it and releases it. The consumer will block until the next shared object has released by the producer. It can then acquire a lock to the storage, process the data and release it back to the pool. In  A suitably designed queue can perform multiple producer/multiple consumer operations with great efficiency. Think a Java thread safe (java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue) semantics but for pointers to storage.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of system I prefer to use for bulk data handling.  The only locks are the short ones that protect the queues and pools while pointers are being pushed/popped.  No thread ever operates on data that can be accessed by another thread, so no contention or locking during the processing of the buffer objects.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the key piece of info there: "As much as possible, prefer to keep each thread’s data isolated (unshared), and let threads instead communicate via asynchronous messages that pass copies of data". I.e. use producer-consumer :)
You can do your own message passing or use something provided by the OS. That's an implementation detail (needs to be done right ofc). The key is to avoid shared data, as in having the same region of memory modified by multiple threads. This can cause hard to find bugs, and even if the code is perfect it will eat performance because of all the locking.

Comment: using message passing still requires shared data between two threads. they just hide the details

Comment: Of course, but it helps you keep the sharing to a minimum. As opposed to having several threads randomly access all your application's data.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple (I'm amazed others wrote such length responses!):

Using a message queue system instead of 'raw' shared data means that you have to get the synchronization (locking/unlocking of resources) right only once, in a central place.

With a message-based system, you can think in higher terms of "messages" without having to worry about synchronization issues anymore. For what it's worth, it's perfectly possible that a message queue is implemented using shared data internally.

Answer (score 0):

I had exact the same question. After reading the answers. I feel:

1. in most typical use case, queue = async, shared memory (locks) = sync. Indeed, you can do a async version of shared memory, but that's more code, similar to reinvent the message passing wheel.
2. Less code = less bug and more time to focus on other stuff.

The pros and cons are already mentioned by previous answers so I will not repeat.